# Convert mp4 voice file to WAV stream

Tags: naudio, naudio-framework

I used this code to resample file and save it but the file sounds like fast-forward recording:

```
using (MediaFoundationReader reader = new MediaFoundationReader(url))
{
    using (ResamplerDmoStream resampledReader = new ResamplerDmoStream(reader, new WaveFormat(16000, 16, 1)))
        {
            using (WaveFileWriter waveWriter = new WaveFileWriter(@"c:\test.wav", resampledReader.WaveFormat))
                {
                    resampledReader.CopyTo(waveWriter);
                }
         }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `WaveFileWriter` must have the same `WaveFormat` as `resampledReader`. So pass in `resampledReader.WaveFormat` to the `WaveFileWriter` constructor.

Comment: if I need the final WAV to be 16kHz, 16 bit, Mono, should I resample once again to make sure that I get the WAV I need?

Comment: you only need to resample once. Use targetsamplerate, not sourcesamplerate.

Comment: I rewrote the code according to your instructions (edited in question) but it still sounds like FF

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what resampling means, but if you need to get the wav from a video, this works...

```
using (var video = new MediaFoundationReader(file))
{
    file = TempWav;
    WaveFileWriter.CreateWaveFile(file, video);
}
```